# How to Find Lookup Values in Multiple Tables in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, vlookup, power-automate, lookup-tables

Hi I am trying to apply lookup on a table to find corresponding values from another table. But since there are null values I want to apply another lookup using a different column in the main table and finding those values in a different lookup table. Though I am able to achieve the 1st problem but unable to apply multiple lookups.

Its the same as applying two vlookups on mutliple table by using multiple columns if a value isn't coming from the 1st column.

Edit:

What I am trying to do is to create an equivalent of this excel formula that I am current using:

=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Account Name]],Table15,5,FALSE),VLOOKUP([@Industry],Table14,2,FALSE)),"Industry Unknown")

I am very new to the M world so can't figure it out. Though I was able to write this code for just one lookup table:

(let AccountName = [Account Name] in Table.SelectRows(#"Account to Segment Mappings", each [Account Name] = AccountName)){0}[Customer Segment]

In power query I have imported two lookup tables - Account to Segment Mappings (Table 15) and Industry to Segment Mappings (table 14).

I am now trying to map Account name in my main table to account name in table 15 and if its not there then lookup Industry column in main table and check in table 14. If it still doesn't find a value return "Industry Unknown"

***Main Table***

| Account Name | Industry | Customer Segment(Need to Map this) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC Bank | Financial |  |
| Z Company | Merchants |  |
| D Company | Merchants |  |
| A Company | Energy/Utilities |  |

***Account to Segment Mapping Table***

| Account Name | Customer Segment |
| --- | --- |
| ABC Bank | Financial |
| Z Company | Merchant & Commerce |
| D Company | Digital Partner |

***Industry to Segment Mapping Table***

| Industry | Customer Segment |
| --- | --- |
| Financial | Financial |
| Energy/Utilities | Merchant & Commerce |
| Merchants | Digital Partner |

The excel code sees account name in Account to Segment Mapping Table using its account name column. If it is not there then using industry column tries to find customer Segment in the industry mapping table. If it isn't found there as well it gives "industry unknown"

Answer (score 0):

Try this which assumes one potential correct answer

Merge each of the other two tables, then add a custom column to see which has desired results using

```
= if Table.RowCount([Account to Segment])=0 then [Industry to Segment]{0}[Customer Segment] else [Account to Segment]{0}[Customer Segment]
```

Full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Account Name"}, #"Account to Segment", {"Account Name"}, "Account to Segment", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Merged Queries", {"Industry"}, #"Industry to Segment", {"Industry"}, "Industry to Segment", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Customer Segment", each try if Table.RowCount([Account to Segment])=0 then [Industry to Segment]{0}[Customer Segment] else  [Account to Segment]{0}[Customer Segment] otherwise null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Account to Segment", "Industry to Segment"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Due to some restrictions I wasn't able to share my data. But I can try to put in a sample asap and share here. What I am trying to do is to create an equivalent of this excel formula that I am current using :

=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Account Name]],Table15,5,FALSE),VLOOKUP([@Industry],Table14,2,FALSE)),"Industry Unknown")

I am very new to the M world so can't figure it out. Though I was able to write this code for just one lookup table:

Comment: (let AccountName = [Account Name] in Table.SelectRows(#"Account to Segment Mappings", 
            each [Account Name] = AccountName)){0}[Customer Segment]

In power query I have imported two lookup tables - Account to Segment Mappings (Table 15) and Industry to Segment Mappings (table 14). I am now trying to map Account  name in my main table to account name in table 15 and if its not there then lookup Industry column and check in table 14. If it still doesn't find a value return "Industry Unknown"

Comment: Fair enough. Due to the restrictions of you not being willing to share made up sample data I am unable to help you any further. Perhaps someone else will be able to assist

Comment: I have added sample data & lookup tables for your reference. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have added some code above

Comment: Hi, this did work. But since the data is relatively large it is slowing down the process. I actually have to combine 5 different data sources, which do not talk to each other. I standardize the entire process in my excel, with a lot of derived columns and mappings. I wanted to automate all this in PQ to save some time there.

Comment: Not exactly sure what that means.  This is powerquery code. Combining multiple sources shouldnt slow anything down, especially with a single merge operation

Comment: What's happening is that its keeps loading data - 10MB loaded/50MB/500MB/ this when the data size is just 50MB. Not sure if I am able to explain you correctly.

I am applying this merged operation on 5 different files to achieve the same result.

Comment: You would need to share your code for additional assistance